# How to detect if Windows Phone have softkeys with C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, softkeys

How to detect if Windows Phone have softkeys with C#/XAML? I saw a question with an answer for Javascript.

Comment: I think it's better to show how it is done in JS since I'm not sure what you're actually asking for.

Comment: If container element (which contains page title through end of phone application page) height < screen height